# How to resolve the 501 Not Implemented Error when creating a bucket as a static website host?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
package com.example.s3;

public class SetStaticWebsiteHost {
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    
    URI myURI = new URI("<company URL>");


    AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
            Credentials.access_key,
            Credentials.secret_access_key);

    S3Configuration config = S3Configuration.builder()
            .pathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .build();

    //Creating the s3 Client that will utilize the credentials and the endpoint provided
    S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
            .endpointOverride(myURI)
            .serviceConfiguration(config)
            .build();

    setWebsiteConfig(s3, "java-test-bucket", "index.html", "error.html");
}
public static void setWebsiteConfig( S3Client s3,
                                     String bucketName,
                                     String indexDoc,
                                     String errorDoc) {

    try {
        WebsiteConfiguration websiteConfig = WebsiteConfiguration.builder()
                .indexDocument(IndexDocument.builder().suffix(indexDoc).build())
                .errorDocument(ErrorDocument.builder().key(errorDoc).build())
                .build();

        PutBucketWebsiteRequest pubWebsiteReq = PutBucketWebsiteRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .websiteConfiguration(websiteConfig)
                .build();

        s3.putBucketWebsite(pubWebsiteReq);

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

This code is taken primarily from the aws-sdk-docs github JavaV2 repo. I keep getting a 501 error with the message: The requested functionality is not implemented. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you show us the error (stacktrace) too?

Comment: I tested this code and it works. The diff here is an URL override is set that seems to be the cause of this error. This thread should not be closed but, a bug should be logged https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2

Comment: Error:                                                                           Exception in thread "main" software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The requested functionality is not implemented. (Service: S3, Status Code: 501, Request ID: 13463d0b:17a04a9f5ae:c765:1571e, Extended Request ID: )
 
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.putBucketWebsite(DefaultS3Client.java:8616)
 at com.example.s3.SetStaticWebsiteHost.setWebsiteConfig(SetStaticWebsiteHost.java:50)
 at com.example.s3.SetStaticWebsiteHost.main(SetStaticWebsiteHost.java:35)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this code and it worked fine.

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.set_website_configuration.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.IndexDocument;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutBucketWebsiteRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.WebsiteConfiguration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.set_website_configuration.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class SetWebsiteConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage: SetWebsiteConfiguration <bucketName> [indexdoc] [errordoc]\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "   bucketName   - the Amazon S3 bucket to set the website configuration on. \n" +
                "   indexdoc - The index document, ex. 'index.html'\n" +
                "              If not specified, 'index.html' will be set.\n" ;

        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = "<bucketName>" ; //args[0];
        String indexDoc = "index.html";
      
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        setWebsiteConfig(s3, bucketName,indexDoc);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.set_website_configuration.main]
    public static void setWebsiteConfig( S3Client s3,
                                         String bucketName,
                                         String indexDoc) {

        try {
            WebsiteConfiguration websiteConfig = WebsiteConfiguration.builder()
                .indexDocument(IndexDocument.builder().suffix(indexDoc).build())
                .build();

            PutBucketWebsiteRequest pubWebsiteReq = PutBucketWebsiteRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .websiteConfiguration(websiteConfig)
                .build();

            s3.putBucketWebsite(pubWebsiteReq);

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
 }
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.set_website_configuration.main]
```